# Два консольных вывода в одном приложении

Tags: c#

Задача такая надо что бы при запуске приложения появлялось 2 консоли, в первой осуществляется вывод данных, во второй мы вводим команды для вывода данных в первой. Как это реализовать. Желательно пример

Comment: Можно использовать WCF. И примеров, и книг достаточно чтобы справиться с задачей.

Comment: Думается, придется делать два независимых приложения, общение между ними — через, например, SignalR. Основное приложение хостит в себе signalr, запускает ведомое приложение, которое цепляется к сокету основного.

Comment: Тебе необходимо породить дочерний процесс для хостинга дополнительных окон консоли. Если тебе это действительно нужно, то [вот пример на С++](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13368/Multiple-consoles-for-a-single-application).

Comment: Одно приложение или два?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это легко реализуется средствами [**RabbitMQ**](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)  + [**Masstransit**](http://masstransit-project.com/).

1) Создаем класс, представляющий сообщение, которым будут обмениваться приложения.

```
public class Message
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

2) Создаем приложение, которое будет отправлять сообщения. Поэтому сперва устанавливаем **[MassTransit.RabbitMQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.RabbitMQ)**

```
Install-Package MassTransit.RabbitMQ -Version 3.5.7
```

---

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     Console.Title = "Publisher";

     var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
            x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h => { }));

     bus.Start();

     var text = "";

     while (text != "выход")
     {
          Console.Write("Введите сообщение: ");
          text = Console.ReadLine();

         var message = new Message()
         {
             Text = text
         };

         bus.Publish(message);
    } 

    bus.Stop();
}
```

3) Создаем приложение, которое будет принимать сообщения. Поэтому так же устанавливаем **[MassTransit.RabbitMQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.RabbitMQ)**

```
Install-Package MassTransit.RabbitMQ -Version 3.5.7
```

---

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
      Console.Title = "Subscriber";

      var bus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(x =>
      {
           var host = x.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h => { });

           x.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "SubscriberQueue", e =>
            e.Handler<Message>(a =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(a.Message.Text);
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }));
     });

     bus.Start();
     Console.ReadKey();
     bus.Stop();
}
```

Comment: Минусы то за что, объяснили бы хоть. Решение не работает или не позволяет реализовать, то что хочет автор вопроса?

Comment: @ sp7 я тебе плюсанул, но по поводу решения слишком оно куда то в дебри, хотелось использовать стандартные библиотеки c#

Comment: @polsok, если два разных приложения устраивают, то можно попробовать реализовать на `NamedPipe`

Comment: @polsok, спасибо за обратную связь. Я привел данный пример, лишь как один из возможных вариантов решения указанной задачи. Он прост, легок в реализацию, плюс использование RabbitMQ + Masstransit предоставляет кучу различных плюшек. Возможно в вашей конкретной ситуации он и не пригодится, но знать о нем будет полезно.